# Как сделать поиск по списку созданным SimpleAdapter с использованием ViewBinder?

Tags: android

Не получается применить поиск  в методе `onTextChanged()`

```
MainActivity.this.sAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);// cannot find symbol variable sAdapter
```

класс:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText mSearch;

    final String ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEXT = "text";
    final String ATTRIBUTE_NAME_PB = "pb";
    final String ATTRIBUTE_NAME_LL = "ll";

    ListView lvSimple;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        int load[] = { 41, 48, 22, 35, 30, 67, 51, 88 };

        ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(
                load.length);
        Map<String, Object> m;
        for (int i = 0; i < load.length; i++) {
            m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEXT, "Day " + (i+1) + ". Load: " + load[i] + "%");
            m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_PB, load[i]);
            m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_LL, load[i]);
            data.add(m);
        }

        String[] from = { ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEXT, ATTRIBUTE_NAME_PB,
                ATTRIBUTE_NAME_LL };

        int[] to = { R.id.tvLoad, R.id.pbLoad, R.id.llLoad };

        SimpleAdapter sAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.item,
                from, to);

        sAdapter.setViewBinder(new MyViewBinder());
        lvSimple = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvSimple);
        lvSimple.setAdapter(sAdapter);

        //--------------- addTextChangedListener() -------------------------------
        mSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mSearch);
        mSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

                //Error: cannot find symbol variable sAdapter
                MainActivity.this.sAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                          int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }// End onCreate()

    class MyViewBinder implements SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder {

        int red = getResources().getColor(R.color.Red);
        int orange = getResources().getColor(R.color.Orange);
        int green = getResources().getColor(R.color.Green);

        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data,
                                    String textRepresentation) {
            int i = 0;
            switch (view.getId()) {
                // LinearLayout
                case R.id.llLoad:
                    i = ((Integer) data).intValue();
                    if (i < 40) view.setBackgroundColor(green); else
                    if (i < 70) view.setBackgroundColor(orange); else
                        view.setBackgroundColor(red);
                    return true;
                // ProgressBar
                case R.id.pbLoad:
                    i = ((Integer) data).intValue();
                    ((ProgressBar)view).setProgress(i);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }



}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<!-- Editext for appearance  searching field -->
<EditText android:id="@+id/mSearch"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint=" Search code.."
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
    android:backgroundTint="#fffb20"
    android:textColorHint="#e4c6c4c4" />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvSimple"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас адаптер объявлен локальной переменной метода `onCreate`, класс про нее ничего не знает. Поэтому либо

```
final SimpleAdapter sAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.item,
            from, to);
```

и

```
sAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs); // MainActivity.this - убрать
```

, либо сделать sAdapter переменной класса MainActivity

```
private SimpleAdapter sAdapter;
```

и

```
sAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.item,
            from, to);
```

Comment: в итоге получаю                                                   "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference"

Comment: @mtb значит где-то у вас не инициализированный List.